# Viewing individual commits after squashing

Tags: git

I noticed that after I squashed a bunch of commits in Git I am able to still view the individual commits. One of the commits that got squashed with all the others was a revert with the commit message referencing the hash of the commit that it reverted. Doing a `git show` on this hash shows me the exact content of this commit. This commit is nowhere in my history since it's been squashed into one commit.

How is this possible? Is this still lying around somewhere in the DAG? Will it eventually be garbage collected by Git when things like `git gc` are run?

Comment: Basically, yes. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: whenever you do almost *anything* in Git, you are really *adding new objects* (commits and files and such) to the repository, leaving existing objects in place.  The main exception is `git gc`, but even that leaves existing objects alone until they expire.

The exact expiration is a bit complicated.  All objects normally live for at least two weeks, just so that they will not be removed during slow operations (that might take seconds or even minutes, during which the objects are not recorded anywhere).

Beyond that, object IDs (primarily commit IDs) written into references—such as commits on branches, or recorded in `HEAD`—normally also get written into a per-branch *reflog* (there's a separate log for `HEAD`).  These are time-stamped when they are written, and such entries live for either 30 days or 90 days by default.  The ones that live longer are those that are *reachable* from the tip of the reference: that is, for `HEAD`, commits that are still in the history of `HEAD`, and for branches, commits that are still on the branch.  The shorter-lived, 30 day expiration, commits are those no longer on the branch (having been rebased and/or squashed, for instance).

These reflog entries serve to protect the objects from the Grim <s>Reaper</s> Collector.  So this means that your old commit will be around for 30 days, not just the 14 days that everything gets.

Deleting a reference, e.g., `git branch -D branch`, causes its reflog to be removed as well.  So if the reflog entry is only in a branch that has been deleted, the grace period may shrink back to 14 days from the object's creation.

Rebased commits are still referenced by the special name `ORIG_HEAD` as well, until something (usually another rebase) overwrites `ORIG_HEAD`.  So this may protect commits well past the 30 day default.

Until `git gc` actually runs and removes an object, though, it will stick around.  It generally will not get copied to clones, but it will potentially still be in your repository, accessible, for years, if `git gc` never needs to run.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer and explains a lot of things, thanks!